# video embedding in beamer

Tags: beamer, embedding

I know this was asked before, and the solution was `y4pdf`, however my question is: do we just compile our latex file with pdfLaTeX or how then?

Because the question was asked over a year ago, are pdf viewers up to speed on this?

Comment: With package `media9` you can use any of `latex+dvips+ps2pdf`, `pdflatex`, `latex+dvipdfmx`, `xelatex`

Answer (score 3):

The 'best of bred' package for including videos into PDFs using LaTeX is currently [`media9`](http://ctan.org/pkg/media9). This uses extensions to the PDF format which are available in Adobe Reader and are of limited availability in other viewers. The older [`movie15`](http://ctan.org/pkg/movie15), by the same author, uses a different approach to including videos, but support for this is also viewer-dependent. Thus it is important to check that the target viewer will display the video.